# Create a new sheet when a cell in column A is updated

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking for assistance building a script. Essentially what I need is a script that can:

a) Create a new sheet within the workbook when a cell in column A is updated, but not create duplicates;

b) Copy and paste a range associated with the column that is updated;

c) Rename the sheet according to the cell in column A that was updated and finally

d) Limit the new sheet to 200 rows.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I know the code below does not run, I have been trying many different variations of things to test functions and wanted to give some sort of idea of what I have been working towards.

```
function onEdit(e){
    var range = e.range;
    if(range.getColumn() == 1){
        range.setNote("COLUMN: "+ range.getColumn());
    };
function insertSheet() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      spreadsheet.insertSheet(58);
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setName(spreadsheet.getRange('A214:A216'));
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('EOD Report Automation MASTER'), true);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('A214:A216'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'EOD Report Automation MASTER\'!A214:J216').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. Would you please share any code or work that you have done so far? This will help other readers understand how to help you. Otherwise, it would not possible to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense `.setName(spreadsheet.getRange('A214:A216'));` setName() require a string and you gave a range.  Read the documentation and update your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example of using an onEdit() to create a new sheet.  When you explain what you want a little more clearly I'll be glad to modify it to meet your requirements.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='Sheet5' && e.range.columnStart==1 && e.value) {
    var nA=e.source.getSheets().map(function(sh,i){return sh.getName();});
    if(nA.indexOf(e.value)==-1) {
      var nsh=e.source.insertSheet(e.value);
    }else{
      e.source.toast(Utilities.formatString("Attempt to create a duplicate Sheet: %s", e.value),"Duplicate Check",-1);
    }
    e.range.activate();
  }
}
```

Enter Sheet Names in Column A.  It will create sheets with the name that you enter unless you enter a duplicate name.

A version that copies data from current sheet to new sheet:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='Sheet5' && e.range.columnStart==1 && e.value) {
    var nA=e.source.getSheets().map(function(sh,i){return sh.getName();});
    if(nA.indexOf(e.value)==-1) {
      var tsh=e.source.insertSheet(e.value);
      var svA=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,3,10).getValues();
      tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,1,svA.length,svA[0].length).setValues(svA);
    }else{
      e.source.toast(Utilities.formatString("Attempt to create a duplicate Sheet: %s", e.value),"Duplicate Check",-1);
    }
    e.range.activate();
  }
}


function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='Sheet5' && e.range.columnStart==1 && e.value) {
    var nA=e.source.getSheets().map(function(sh,i){return sh.getName();});
    if(nA.indexOf(e.value)==-1) {
      var tsh=e.source.insertSheet(e.value);
      var srg=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,3,10);
      var trg=tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,1);
      srg.copyTo(trg);
    }else{
      e.source.toast(Utilities.formatString("Attempt to create a duplicate Sheet: %s", e.value),"Duplicate Check",-1);
    }
    e.range.activate();
  }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you kindly. Finally, instead of the script creating a blank sheet, I need to figure out how to automatically import the relative range '\'Sheet5\'!A2:J24'

Comment: Import relative ranges from where?  We can put a formula somewhere on the new sheet what would like it to be?

Comment: From the same sheet that is being updated, Sheet 5 in this case. The range is an extension of the column/rows being updated in the code above. 

For example, currently when A2 on Sheet 5 is entered with "Test" is created a new Sheet called "Test".  Now I would like to import or copy and paste A2:J4 from the same Sheet 5, into the new "Test" sheet, but have the script be relative to the cell being updated like the code above.

Comment: Do you want them copied into the same range on the new sheet?

Comment: They should be copied to A1:J3 of the new sheet. Thanks

Comment: Works well but I also need to keep the formatting from Sheet 5, and I forgot that the range imported from Sheet 5 has values and formulas that need to .get and .set.

~
      var svA=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,2,10).getValues();
      var svB=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,3,10).getFormulas(); 
      tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,1,svA.length,svA[0].length).setValues(svA);
      tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,1,svB.length,svB[0].length).setFormulas(svB);
    }else{

Comment: I'm using the range.copyTo now so formats will remain.

Comment: Your going to have to run with it a while on your own.  It's time for you to dig into the documentation and figure it out yourself.

Comment: Your use of copyTo was exactly what I needed its perfect now thank you Cooper.